# Google App Engine app.yaml PHP scripting parameters

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml, sitemap.xml

In my GAE PHP app.yaml i am trying to do this:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /sitemap.xml    
  static_files: sitemap.xml
  upload: /sitemap\.xml

- url: /MyOneLink
  script: /myDynamicContent.php?myparam=hardcoded_value_1

- url: /MySecondLink
  script: /myDynamicContent.php?myparam=hardcoded_value_2
```

so one can browse http://example.com/MyOneLink and get the result of the dynamic php (which depends of the hardcoded myparam value)

the problem is that when browsing, nothing is shown.
any idea ?

btw: you can figure out why i am also publishing a "sitemap.xml": it will be used to expose all myLinks

thanks
diego

Comment: 1) if you called your file app.yamp, it's app.yaml, so that could be a reason. 2) we would need to see your code.

Comment: Patrice, thanks for replying. the file is actually "app.yaml" (typo corrected). what code do you need ?

Comment: myDynamicContent.php probably? since it doesn't display, I'd guess this is the rootcause :)

Comment: <?php

$rd = strtoupper(substr(md5(time()), 0, 10));
echo ("random " . $rd);
echo "<br>";

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) echo "GET Key: $key Val: $value<br>";
?>

Comment: gae is responsing "404" error

Comment: ... I just clicked reading your yaml... I don't think you need to add your query param (I don't code in php, but my Python apps never had the full query params in them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers would be fine for a finite number of values that are hardcoded (as shown in question).

But if you want to work with a truly dynamic version with infinite possibilities of values, you may think of the following (**does not work**):

```
- url: /MyLinks/(.*)/?
  script: /myDynamicContent.php?myparam=\1
```

The above does not work. You can workaround the problem by using a simple PHP **hack**.

Update the `app.yaml` to:

```
- url: /MyLinks/.*
  script: /myDynamicContent.php
```

In `myDynamicContent.php`, get the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse this string to get the intended value for `myparam`.

*Update! More elegant method:*

```
<?php
$requestURI = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$requestURI = explode("/", $requestURI);
$myparam = $requestURI[2];
echo $myparam;
?>
```

> Since `parse_url` always gets the path info, we can safely depend on hardcoded indices. The array produced by `explode` for string `/MyLinks/value_1` will contain an empty string at index **0**, `MyLinks` at **1**, `value_1` at **2**, and so on.

*Original clunkier method:*

```
<?php
$requestURI = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($requestURI); $i++) {
    if (strcmp($requestURI[$i], "MyLinks") == 0) {
        $myparam = $requestURI[$i + 1];
        break;
    }
}
echo $myparam;
?>
```

*Tip:* You can use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass parameters in the "script:" parameter.

One way to fix this would be two have two "entry" scripts, which then include your main script, like this:

```
<?php
$_GET['myparam'] = 'hardcoded_value_1';
require('main_script.php');
```

Which you can then reference in app.yaml

This is probably the quickest way to make your existing code work (although there are better ways to do it).

Comment: great answer. what about mod_rewrite simulation?

Answer (score 0):

reading the oficial doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite 
i did this:

```
<$php
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], PHP_URL_PATH);

if ($path == '/path') {
}
?>
```